# Perl Search Multiple Keyword with Regex

Tags: perl, hash, key

I'm searching for a list of Keywords from a file. I am able to match the whole keyword, but for some keywords i need to match a first part of word. For Example

```
DES
AES
https:// --- here it should match the word starting with https:// but my code considers the whole word and skips it.
```

For example using the above keywords I would want to match `DES`, `DES` and `https://` only from the below input:

```
DES some more words
DESTINY and more...
https://example.domain.com
http://anotherexample.domain.com # note that this line begins with http://, not https://
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open STDOUT, '>>', "my_stdout_file.txt";
#die qq[Usage: perl $0 <keyword-file> <search-file> <file-name>\n] unless  @ARGV == 3;

my $filename = $ARGV[2];
chomp ($filename);
open my $fh, q[<], shift or die $!; --- This file handle Opening all the 3 arguments. I need to Open only 2.

my %keyword = map { chomp; $_ => 1 } <$fh>;
print "$fh\n";
while ( <> ) {
    chomp;
    my @words = split;
    for ( my $i = 0; $i <= $#words; $i++ ) {
            if ( $keyword{^$words[ $i ] } ) {
                    print "Keyword Found for file:$filename\n";
                    printf qq[$filename Line: %4d\tWord position: %4d\tKeyword: %s\n],
                            $., $i, $words[ $i ];
            }
    }
}
close ($fh);
```

Comment: How can the program know whether you want a complete word match or just a partial match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working solution for what I think you're trying to achieve. Let me know if not:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/ say /;

my %keywords;

while(<DATA>){
    chomp;
    my ($key) = split;
    my $length = length($key);
    $keywords{$key} = $length;
}

open my $in, '<', 'in.txt' or die $!;


while(<$in>){
    chomp;
    my $firstword = (split)[0];

        for my $key (keys %keywords){
            if ($firstword =~ m/$key/){ 
                my $word = substr($firstword, 0, $keywords{$key});
                say $word;
            }
        }
}
__DATA__
Keywords:-
DES
AES 
https:// - here it should match the word starting with https:// but my code considers the whole word and skipping it.
```

For an input file containing:

```
here are some words over multiple
lines
that may or
may not match your keywords:
DES DEA AES SSE
FOO https:
https://example.domain.com
```

This produces the output:

```
 DES
 https://
```

Comment: I'm getting error running the code.   **Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//)**